# Which BIONICLE combiner sets do official instructions exist for creating?

Tags: instructions, bionicle

There is a diversity of BIONICLE combiner sets (sets made by *combining* multiple individual sets together) for various groups including Toa, Matoran, Bohrok, Rahkshi, Dark Hunters, and a number of Rahi species, listed [here](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aCombiner_sets). They're encountered in the physical sets, in the comics and even in some of the movies.

Instructions for building some of these combiner sets can be found in the manuals for each of the individual sets used in making them. Which combiner sets are these?

Comment: Some of the "combiner sets" referenced in the wiki link above are in fact alternative builds. I don't think these should be counted... unless LEGO made instructions to build them, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Should this include non-bionicle sets too?

Comment: @Pubby8: If there are official instructions for combining with non-BIONICLE sets, I suppose they're fine.

Comment: I added in ThrowBot combiners. I don't know how to format it correctly.

Comment: @Pubby8: Oh, if you're referring to entire combiner sets that are outside the BIONICLE line, then no. Sorry I wasn't clear :S

Comment: I'll remove it then. If a ThrowBot question gets made then there is always the revision history to go off of.

Comment: @Pubby8 Yea ThrowBots and Hero Factory are outside the straight up Bionicle storyline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be the format we use for a community wiki

**"official" name:**
**Set(s) Release Date:**
**Set(s) required:**
**Model Picture:**
**Link to instructions:**

**"official" name:** Akamai
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2001~
**Set(s) required:** Tahu, Onua, and Pohatu(8531)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Akamai]
**Link to instructions:** n/a

**"official" name:** Wairuha
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2001
**Set(s) required:** Gali(8533), Kopaka(8536), and Lewa(8535)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Wairuha]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

**"official" name:** Mata Nui Cow
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2001
**Set(s) required:** Pohatu(8531) and Gali(8533)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Mata Nui Cow]

**Link to instructions:** http://www.bzpower.com/Imaging/stories/mukau_instructions.jpg

**"official" name:** Mata Nui Fishing Bird
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2002
**Set(s) required:** Kohrak Va(8551) and Nuhvok Va(8555)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Mata Nui Fishing Bird]
**Link to instructions:** http://club.lego.com/en-us/BuildIt/BuildingInstructions/fishing.aspx (link now dead)

**"official" name:** Bohrok Va Kaita 1
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2001
**Set(s) required:** Gahlok Va(8550), Kohrak Va(8551) and Lehvak Va(8552)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Bohrok Va Kaita 1]
**Link to instructions:** n/a

**"official" name:** Bohrok Va Kaita 2
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2001
**Set(s) required:** Pahrak Va(8553), Tahnok Va(8554) and Nuhvok Va(8555)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Bohrok Va Kaita 2]
**Link to instructions:** n/a

**"official" name:** Bohrok Kaita Ja
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2002~
**Set(s) required:** Lehvak(8564), Kohrak(8565), and Gahlok(8562)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Bohrok Kaita Ja]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

**"official" name:** Bohrok Kaita Za
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2002~
**Set(s) required:** Bohrok(8561), Tahnok(8563), and Pahrak(8560)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Bohrok Kaita Za]
**Link to instructions:**

**"official" name:** Wairuha Nuva
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2003~
**Set(s) required:** Gali Nuva(8570), Lewa Nuva(8567), and Kopaka Nuva(8571)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Wairuha Nuva]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

**"official" name:** Akamai Nuva
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2003~
**Set(s) required:** Tahu Nuva(8572), Onua Nuva(8566), and Pohatu Nuva(8568)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Akamai Nuva]
**Link to instructions:** n/a

**"official" name:** Bohrok Kaita Ja-Kal
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2003~
**Set(s) required:** Lehvak-Kal, Kohrak-Kal, and Gahlok-Kal
**Model Picture:**

[image: Bohrok Kaita Ja-Kal]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

**"official" name:** Rahkshi Kaita Za
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2003~
**Set(s) required:** Turahk(8592), Lerahk(8589) and Kurahk(8588)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Rahkshi Kaita Za]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

**"official" name:** Rahkshi Kaita Vo
**Set(s) Release Date:** 2003~
**Set(s) required:** Panrahk(8587), Guurahk(8590) and Vorahk(8591)
**Model Picture:**

[image: Rahkshi Kaita Vo]
**Link to instructions:** N/A

Comment: That's pretty well the extent of my knowledge and instructions, so if anyone knows of any more models, be sure to add them, even if your knowledge isn't complete.